# Radio Buttons in angular2 not working as expected

Tags: angular

Hie...I have a form which has radio buttons inside it. In this there are two groups of radio buttons...

1.used to select the preferred phone among the list

2.Select preferred email among the list

when i select a radio option among phones it shows true but if i select the radio button in emails group the selected value in phones will be set to false...I have made a plunker demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/gSosX6kueTxu64CDfjQg?p=preview

```
myForm: ControlGroup;  
Phones: ControlGroup;
Emails:ControlGroup;
constructor(fb:FormBuilder){
this.Phones=fb.group({
      Phone1:[''],
      Phone2:[''],
      Phone3:['']
});
this.Emails=fb.group({
  Email1:[''],
  Email2:['']
});
this.myForm = fb.group({  
});
}
this.myForm.addControl('Phones', this.Phones));
this.myForm.addControl('Emails', this.Emails);
```

This is how i am accessing the values of radio buttons and assigning to main control group...Somebody please help me how to get the values of radio buttons correctly in this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue that multiple radio buttons in the same ControlGroup don't work https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7051

This [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7051#issuecomment-198526932) from cur3n4 shows a workaround

```
import {RadioControlRegistry, RadioControlValueAccessor} from 'angular2/src/common/forms/directives/radio_control_value_accessor';

// TODO Monkey patching Radio buttons until https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7051 is fixed
export class CustomRadioControlRegistry extends RadioControlRegistry {

    select(accessor: RadioControlValueAccessor) {
        (<any>this)._accessors.forEach((c) => {
            if (c[0].control.root === accessor._control.control.root
              && c[1] !== accessor && c[1]._elementRef.nativeElement.name === (<any>accessor)._elementRef.nativeElement.name) {
              c[1].fireUncheck();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> And then when bootstrapping the app, I am replacing the `RadioControlRegistry` with my implementation:
>   `provide(RadioControlRegistry, {useClass: CustomRadioControlRegistry})`

Comment: Oh...I didn't know about this issue...Thank you @Gunter

Comment: I haven't tried the workaround myself yet but looks promising.

Comment: The alternative which you mentioned works perfectly but i dont want to add this code in my application since it causes dependecies...I will wait till angular fixes this issue